# MIDI sound samples of standard instruments

Tags: objective-c, ipad, midi

Does anybody know where I can find a MIDI library with pre-recorded sound samples of standard instruments? I need to integrate that into my Objective-C application code.

Comment: were you able to find anything on getting & playing midi files? Kind Regards, Qam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... there's no such thing exactly as a "MIDI library".  What you are looking for is a sampler, which is an instrument that takes MIDI notes and plays out audio samples based on the note number.

In any case, the Iowa Orchestra recorded a lovely set of samples for a number of instruments, which can be found here:

http://www.sonicspot.com/news/free-musical-instrument-samples.html

The samples are great quality, and broken down by type and note number.

Comment: Ah, the curse of the dead link.